# How should i convert a str list to a simple list?

Tags: python

I have something like:

```
   '[356, 1079, 1220, 1060, 3039, 1197, 4085, 4002, 2395]'
```

but I want:

```
   [356, 1079, 1220, 1060, 3039, 1197, 4085, 4002, 2395]
```

how can I do this in python?

Answer (score 4):

```
a =  ['[356, 1079, 1220, 1060, 3039, 1197, 4085, 4002, 2395]']
a_real_list = json.loads(a[0])
```

or

```
a_real_list = ast.literal_eval(a[0])
```

or

```
a_real_list_of_str = a[0][1:-1].split(", ")
```